# Best way to declare N number of workers in a supervisor, without knowing N beforehand

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

I'm developing an application with 1 supervisor and several workers. Each one of those workers will just open a tcp socket, execute a listen, and then accept connections, spawning a process for each client as they arrive (I dont mind supervising these).

I'd like to make the listening addresses configurable in the application configuration, so I can have as many addresses to listen as needed (at least 1 address is needed, but any number can be specified). Each address is an ip (or hostname) and a port address. So far, nothing new.

My question is about how to declare, start, and supervise an unknown number of workers. My solution was to dynamically generate (at runtime) the result of the init/1 function in the supervisor code, like this:

```
-define(
   CHILD(Name, Args),
   {Name, {
       ?MODULE, start_listen, Args
       }, permanent, 5000, worker, [?MODULE]
   }
).

init([]) ->
   {ok, Addresses} = application:get_env(listen),
   Children = lists:map(
       fun(Address) ->
           {X1,X2,X3} = os:timestamp(),
           ChildName = string:join([
               "Listener-",
               integer_to_list(X1),
               integer_to_list(X2),
               integer_to_list(X3)
           ], ""),
           ?CHILD(ChildName, [Address])
       end,
       Addresses
   ),
   {ok, { {one_for_one, 5, 10}, Children }}.
```

This allows me to dynamically generate a name for each worker and also generate the worker definitions. So:

1. Is this solution acceptable? It seems to me that it's not that elegant. Is there any standard solution (or best practice, etc) for this kind of use cases?
2. I know about the "simple_one_for_one" strategy, that allows to dynamically add workers to a supervisor. But can it also be used to dynamically generate the worker's names? Is it better (in any way) to use "simple_one_for_one" instead of my own solution that uses "one_for_one"? (again, for *this* particular situation).

Thanks in advance, and sorry for the long post! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `simple_one_for_one` :

in the init function of your workers, you can register them in a table to associate a name with their PID, so you will be able to get the pid from the name.

You can use the `global` module (or [gproc](https://github.com/uwiger/gproc) !) to associate a name with a pid. When a process dies, the name is automatically deleted by `global` or `gproc`, so when the supervisor restarts the child, the name is available.

You would pass the names in the arguments list (2nd param) of supervisor:start_child/2

Using `simple_one_for_one` will allow you to dynamically add more listeners after your supervisor initialization.

If you need this feature, `simple_one_for_one` is the good solution.

If you stick with your solution of a dynamic content inside the init function of your sup, you could clean the code like this, it may, or may not, seem more elegant :

```
-define(
   CHILD(Name, Args),
   {Name, {
       ?MODULE, start_listen, Args
       }, permanent, 5000, worker, [?MODULE]
   }
).

generate_names(Adresses) -> generate_names(Adresses, 1, []).

generate_names([], _, Acc) -> Acc;
generate_names([Addr|Addresses], ID, Acc) -> generate_names(Addresses, ID+1, [{id_name(ID), Addr}|Acc]).

id_name(ID) -> "listener-" ++ integer_to_list(ID).

init([]]) ->
   {ok, Addresses} = application:get_env(listen),
   Children = [?CHILD(Name, Address) || {Name, Address} <- generate_names(Addresses)],
   {ok, { {one_for_one, 5, 10}, Children }}.
```

Or use a `lists:foldl` instead of all theese little functions to keep the code short.

But anyway i would pass the Adresses in the Args list of init and not call `get_env` inside init to keep it pure.

Comment: Thanks! I'm inclined to think that my original code is a little more readable and simpler (i.e: you dont have to move a lot your eyes to see what's going on), but +1 for suggesting to pass the addresses as an argument of init

Comment: hmm.. I have experience with many tcp workers with one listener, and I did not do this way. My gut says this approach is not well designed. I followed this instead, http://www.trapexit.org/Building_a_Non-blocking_TCP_server_using_OTP_principles. Basically you start a supervisor to monitor one worker whenever you listen to the port. Long way to go buddy, don't hurry. design is the most important and you need to take time to read everything.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, I know that you want to get the number of children from environment. 
In the source code of worker_pool_sup.erl of rabbitmq open source project, I have read the almost similar requirement code, and the code is much elegant, I think it is helpful to you.
3 files are related, worker_pool_sup.erl, worker_pool_worker.erl, work_pool.erl.

The following code is from worker_pool_sup.erl.

```
init([WCount]) ->
    {ok, {{one_for_one, 10, 10},
          [{worker_pool, {worker_pool, start_link, []}, transient,
            16#ffffffff, worker, [worker_pool]} |
           [{N, {worker_pool_worker, start_link, [N]}, transient, 16#ffffffff,
             worker, [worker_pool_worker]} || N <- lists:seq(1, WCount)]]}}.
```

For how to use it, the following code is from worker_pool.erl

```
get_worker_pid(WId) ->
    [{WId, Pid, _Type, _Modules} | _] =
        lists:dropwhile(fun ({Id, _Pid, _Type, _Modules})
                              when Id =:= WId -> false;
                            (_)               -> true
                        end,
                        supervisor:which_children(worker_pool_sup)),
    Pid.
```

Comment: I wanted something more than a copy&paste, but thank you for pointing out the source